# Python file operations

Tags: python, file-io

I got an err "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" with this python program:

```
from sys import argv
file = open("test.txt", "a+")
print file.tell() # not at the EOF place, why?
print file.read() # 1
file.write("Some stuff will be written to this file.") # 2
# there r some errs when both 1 & 2
print file.tell()
file.close()
```

what seems to be the problem? These 2 cases below are ok:

```
from sys import argv
file = open("test.txt", "a+")
print file.tell() # not at the EOF place, why?
# print file.read() # 1
file.write("Some stuff will be written to this file.") # 2
# there r some errs when both 1 & 2
print file.tell()
file.close()
```

and:

```
from sys import argv
file = open("test.txt", "a+")
print file.tell() # not at the EOF place, why?
print file.read() # 1
# file.write("Some stuff will be written to this file.") # 2
# there r some errs when both 1 & 2
print file.tell()
file.close()
```

still, why

```
print file.tell() # not at the EOF place, why?
```

does not print the size of the file, is "a+" the append-mode? then the file pointer should point to EOF?

i'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Where do you get the error? The problem seems to be that you're trying to read a file opened in append mode

Comment: Also, are you sure that text.txt exists?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. `tell` returns `0` just after opening the file, of course, why would you expect anything else?

Comment: Can you add the version of Python you are using and the operating system?

Comment: See my updated answer, this fix should work. I tried it on the same platform+python version as you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python uses stdio's fopen function and passes the mode as argument. I am assuming you use windows, since @Lev says the code works fine on Linux.

The following is from the [fopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) documentation of windows, this may be a clue to solving your problem:

> When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading
>   and writing are allowed (the file is said to be open for "update").
>   However, when you switch between reading and writing, there must be an
>   intervening fflush, fsetpos, fseek, or rewind operation. The current
>   position can be specified for the fsetpos or fseek operation, if
>   desired.

So, the solution is to add `file.seek()` before the `file.write()` call. For appending to the end of the file, use `file.seek(0, 2)`.

For your reference, file.seek works as follows:

> To change the file object’s position, use f.seek(offset, from_what).
>   The position is computed from adding offset to a reference point; the
>   reference point is selected by the from_what argument. A from_what
>   value of 0 measures from the beginning of the file, 1 uses the current
>   file position, and 2 uses the end of the file as the reference point.
>   from_what can be omitted and defaults to 0, using the beginning of the
>   file as the reference point.

[reference: [http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html]](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

As mentioned by @lvc in the comments and @Burkhan in his answer, you can use the newer open function from the [io module](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html). However, I want to point out that the write function does not work exactly the same in this case -- you need to provide unicode strings as input [Simply prefix a `u` to the string in your case]:

```
from io import open
fil = open('text.txt', 'a+')
fil.write('abc') # This fails
fil.write(u'abc') # This works
```

Finally, please avoid using the name 'file' as a variable name, since it refers to a builtin type and will be silently over-written, leading to some hard to spot errors.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, I couldn't make sure of that from the documentation, but you're right, the code works

Comment: Moreover, it opens non-existent files without any errors, too.

Comment: Yep, but it fails when the file has some text in it

Comment: It doesn't, at least on my system.

Comment: I am using windows, Python 2.7, what about you?

Comment: @Dhara, sure, file 'test.txt' exists.

Comment: If this is a platform difference, the easiest fix is: `from io import open`. This uses the new `open` from Py3, which behaves the same way everywhere it runs.

Comment: @user1477871 yeah, `from io import open` works in Py2.7 - it replaces the builtin `open` function with the newer one (that is now the default).

Comment: More data! When running from the console under vscode, I get this annoying error. If instead I run from cmder (aka http://cmder.net/) it runs fine. Just for completeness, a vanilla cmd.exe also works. So there may be something about how vscode handles... I/O?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to use `open` from [`io`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html)

```
D:\>python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = open('file.txt','a+')
>>> f.tell()
0L
>>> f.close()
>>> from io import open
>>> f = open('file.txt','a+')
>>> f.tell()
22L
```