# file overwritten in spite of conditional

Tags: python, io, conditional-statements

I have some files, some are populated. Try to put a single zero in each file that is not populated, using a list of the file names, and testing each file for content:

```
for n in list_of_files:
    nam = n[2]
    fil = '.'.join([nam, 'fil'])    # adds .fil extension to filename
    with open(fil,'r+') as f:
        if not f.readline():        # check file contents
            print 'empty file: ' + fil
        f.seek(0)
        f.write('0')
```

The script had identified the files with something in them just fine, with lines such as `if f.readline()` `print 'nam'` but when the above block was run, all of the files were overwritten. No worries, but wondering what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are writing regardless of whether the file is populated or not, try this instead

```
for n in list_of_files:
    nam = n[2]
    fil = '.'.join([nam, 'fil'])    # adds .fil extension to filename
    with open(fil,'r+') as f:
        if not f.readline():        # check file contents
            print 'empty file:', fil
            f.seek(0)
            f.write('0')
```

Comment: +1 You're right, though you can remove the `seek(0)` as for an empty file the file pointer is already at the beginning.

Comment: Without seek(0) there is an error message: `IOError: [Errno 0] Error` as dealt with in the following [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176724/python-file-operations).