# "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" error in Python

Tags: python, regex, runtime-error

I have a script that should append something to a file, but it is raising an error that I don't understand and not sure how it is being triggered.

Here is the code:

```
import re

num_words = "four kiddiewinks|four children|four kids"
words_list = num_words.split('|')

def append_2synonym(words_list, num_words):
    with open('test2 words.txt', 'a+') as f:
        read_f = f.read()
        patt = r'^' + words_list[0] + '\|'
        result = re.search(patt, read_f, re.MULTILINE)
        if result == None:
            f.write("\n" + num_words)
        else:
            print "\nNo match found in '2 words.txt' file"

append_2synonym(words_list, num_words)
```

Here is the contents of the 'test2 words.txt' file:

```
five kiddiewinks|five kids|five children
mobile phone|cell phone|cellular phone
stinky cheese|smelly cheese
```

Here is the full error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Magic Briefcase\My Python Scripts\Spin Scripts\synonyms\testing2.py", line 16, in <module>
    append_2synonym(words_list, num_words)
  File "D:\Magic Briefcase\My Python Scripts\Spin Scripts\synonyms\testing2.py", line 12, in append_2synonym
    f.write("\n" + num_words)
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176724/python-file-operations, are you on Windows?

Comment: Yep, I am using windows 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting answer from [Python file operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176724/python-file-operations), when switching between reading and writing on Windows, there must be an intervening fflush, fsetpos, fseek, or rewind operation.

Here is a possible fix:

```
import re

num_words = "four kiddiewinks|four children|four kids"
words_list = num_words.split('|')

def append_2synonym(words_list, num_words):
    with open('test2 words.txt', 'a+') as f:
        read_f = f.read()
        patt = r'^' + words_list[0] + '\|'
        result = re.search(patt, read_f, re.MULTILINE)
        if result == None:
            f.seek(0,2) # change is here !!
            f.write("\n" + num_words)
        else:
            print "\nNo match found in '2 words.txt' file"

append_2synonym(words_list, num_words)
```

In `f.seek(0,2)`, `2` is the `from_what` argument. A `from_what` value of `0` measures from the beginning of the file, `1` uses the current file position, and `2` uses the end of the file as the reference point. `from_what` can be omitted and defaults to `0`, using the beginning of the file as the reference point.

Comment: Since `f.read()` reads to EOF, the original *should* work: the C standard allows switching from read to write mode if read encounters EOF.  If this does fix it, that implies the C library on (some compilers and/or some versions of?) Windows gets this wrong.

Comment: @btoueg - thanks this is working. I tried it several times and the apeending keeps working and growing the 'test2 words.txt' file. I just tried looking at the python docs about `.seek()`, but I could not totally figure out `f.seek(0,2)`. I understand that the first argument `0` effectively rewinds to the beginning of the file, but what is the `2` doing?

Comment: I've edited the answer. For more details, go check the answer I am referring to.

Comment: Thank you. I will now study that answer in more details. I appreciate the help :-)