# Python: IOError: [Errno 0] Error when reading JSON

Tags: python, json, ioerror

I have the following code, which takes some JSON data, reads it into a dictionary, does some manipulation, then writes it back.

```
import json
file = open('data.json', 'r+')
data = json.loads(file.read())
#Do something with our data
data = json.dumps(data)
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

When I run said code, I get the following:

> IOError: [Errno 0]

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283118/python-ioerror-errno-0-error-what-is-triggering-this-error-in-my-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - "IOError: \[Errno 0\] Error". What is Triggering This Error In My Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283118/python-ioerror-errno-0-error-what-is-triggering-this-error-in-my-code)