# Error when opening file: IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Tags: python, pickle, ioerror

I am trying to open a file in my python code, but I get the error 'IOError: [Errno 0] Error'. You can see my code below:

```
fd = open('./Aeolis_data/AeolisTimeStamp.pck1', 'wt')
prevTimeStamp = pickle.load(fd)
```

I get the same error when I try 'wb' as a second argument in the open function. I have tried putting 'rt' as a second argument in the open function, but then I get the error 'EOFError'. With 'rb', the same happens.

Next to this I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283118/python-ioerror-errno-0-error-what-is-triggering-this-error-in-my-code/19283267) (fd.seek(0, 2)), but it does not work as well. 
Does anyone know what the reason of this error could be and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: To _load_ data, open the file in _read_ mode.

Comment: Is Aeolis_data a subdirectory of your current directory? Do you have write rights there?

Comment: "w" mode deletes the old file. Its pointless to try to unpickle a brand new file with nothing in it.

Comment: You want "rb" (read binary) but you need to regenerate the file because the "wt" test overwrote it with a blank file. And BTW, post the stack trace! We don't know if the problem was the open of the json load.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for your help! My file finally works with 'rb' now.