# "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" in python 2.7 when printing

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a "IOError: [Errno 0] Error" print error, when printing with python 2.7 on Windows. I use Pycharm as an IDE.

In my current problem, I have two successive print. The first one on the standard output (console) and the second one in a file. And the error seems to provide from the first one.

There are some similar topics that can be found on StackOverflow:

- [Python file operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176724/python-file-operations)
- ["IOError: [Errno 0] Error" error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283118/ioerror-errno-0-error-error-in-python)

The common method described is to go at the end of the file with `f.seek(0,2)`. Unfortunately, this method is not available on the standard console output. Besides, `f.tell()` doesn't help either. I tried the synchronization `sys.stdout.flush()`, without success.

For some reason, disabling the option *Emulate terminal in output console* seems to solve the problem, except that it breaks some of the character (unicode I guess) display...

How to avoid this error/problem?

Comment: Please provide an example of failing code.

Comment: This is a PyCharm bug (it's in all JetBrain's products).

Comment: @thebjorn: It would make sense. That would explain why disabling this Pycharm option solves the problem. Are you aware if there is any plan to fix that?

Comment: If I remember correctly the bug is very old, so I'm guessing no...