# Store input based on computer and change stored input on command

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-idle

Fixed code;

```
if os.path.isfile(external_file):
    with open(external_file) as in_f:
        name = in_f.read()
else:
    name = raw_input("What's your name?")
    with open(external_file, "w") as out_f:
        out_f.write(name)
```

The problem is.

It refers to every computer that uses it with the name that is stored in .txt.
I need to have a different .txt for every mac address/ip/computer

I also need the name to be changed on command from the user

Also if there is no name in .txt it does not ask for the name?

Comment: Can you please elaborate further what problem are you facing? What do you mean by `problems occur when the code is online as a chat bot and uses the one .txt for every user and so will call every user the first name it has been told` Also please fix your code's identation!

Comment: @user3735393 There's some stuff in your code that makes no sense...For example, if `external_file` isn't a file (you probably should be using `os.path.exists`, rather than `os.path.isfile`), you try to open it (which will likely fail because the file probably doesn't exist), and then do nothing (`pass`). What's the point of that? You also have an `else` block without any corresponding `if` at the end of your example, which I'm guessing is an indentation issue.

Comment: @dano, how would it fail if the file does not exist?

Comment: @dano I re-worded the question

Comment: @Padric Cunningham can you answer?

Comment: @user3735393, you should add a step by step list point example of what you need to achieve with your code. The more information you give the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham His original code said `if not os.path.isfile(external_file): <open file that is not a file using "with", then "pass" inside the with block>`. He has since edited it.

Comment: @dano using "a" would create the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ugh, I completely missed the 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to do this in such way that first simply ask  the user's name, then check if the file `names.txt` exists or not, if not then create a new file with the name names.txt and append the user's name to it. If the file exists now check if it contains user's name or not, if it contains then say 'Hi+ name', else append the name to the file.

Here is a quick and dirty fix for your code (can be improved further!):

```
import os
#hard code the path to the external file
external_file = 'names.txt'
#Ask the user's name
name = raw_input("What's your name?")
#if file exists, use it to load name, else create a new file
if not os.path.exists(external_file):
    with open(external_file, "a") as f: # using "a" will append to the file
        f.write(name)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    #if file exists, use it to load name, else ask user
    with open(external_file, "r+") as f:# r+ open a file for reading & writing
        lines = f.read().split('\n') # split the names 
        #print lines
        if name in lines:
            print "Hi {}".format(name)
        else:
            f.seek(0,2) # Resolves an issue in Windows
            f.write(name)
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()
```

**Update**: Modified version to check for a harcoded name only:

```
import os
#hard code the path to the external file
external_file = 'names.txt'
username = 'testuser'# Our hardcoded name

#if file doesn' exists, create a new file
if not os.path.exists(external_file):
    #Ask the user's name
    name = raw_input("What's your name?")
    with open(external_file, "a") as f: # using "a" will append to the file
        f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    #if file exists, use it to load name, else ask user
    with open(external_file, "r+") as f:# r+ open a file for reading & writing
        lines = f.read().split('\n') # split the names 
        print lines
        if username in lines: #Check if the file has any username as 'testuser'
            print "Hi {}".format(username)
        else: # If there is no username as 'testuser' then ask for a name
            name = raw_input("What's your name?")
            f.seek(0,2) # Resolves an issue in Windows
            f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()
```

Reason for using `file.seek()` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176772/2382792).

Comment: That asks for the name everytime, even when the name is in the .txt?

Comment: Yes, it asks for the name even if the name is in the file, but it won't append it to the file if the name is already in the file. It asks the name because it has to search if the given name exists in the file or not. If you don't provide a name then how shall the code know what name to display?

Comment: How do i make it so it doesn't ask for the name if the name is in the .txt ?

Comment: Im sorry for asking but where does it write the username to the .txt?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. Ok you asked `How do i make it so it doesn't ask for the name if the name is in the .txt ?` In that case you have to hardcode the name in code too. I have modified the code again. Now if the names.txt files contain a name as `testuser` then it won't ask for any name, else it shall ask for the name and write it to the names.txt file.

Comment: What would the code be then for allowing the user to ask the bot to change the name it has on file?

Comment: I modified the code as per your comment, the modified code will simply check if the file exists or not, if yes then check if it contains our hardcoded name `testuser`, if yes then don't ask for name. Else it will ask for a name and store it to the file. If the file doesn't exists at all then it ask for a name and then will simply create a file and write the entered name into it. Well you may ask a new question if you have any more questions. You can't ask more than one questions at a time. Just ask a new question provide the details and you'll get answer there.

Comment: Sorry. I shall post the question again. I had a problem. I worded it wrong and got thrown off completly.