# Error when trying to read and write multiple files

Tags: python, regex

I modified the code based on the comments from experts in this thread. Now the script reads and writes all the individual files. The script reiterates, highlight and write the output. The current issue is, after highlighting the last instance of the search item, the script removes all the remaining contents after the last search instance in the output of each file.

Here is the modified code:

```
import os
import sys
import re

source = raw_input("Enter the source files path:")

listfiles = os.listdir(source)

for f in listfiles:
    filepath = source+'\\'+f
    infile = open(filepath, 'r+')
    source_content = infile.read()

    color = ('red')
    regex = re.compile(r"(\b be \b)|(\b by \b)|(\b user \b)|(\bmay\b)|(\bmight\b)|(\bwill\b)|(\b's\b)|(\bdon't\b)|(\bdoesn't\b)|(\bwon't\b)|(\bsupport\b)|(\bcan't\b)|(\bkill\b)|(\betc\b)|(\b NA \b)|(\bfollow\b)|(\bhang\b)|(\bbelow\b)", re.I)

    i = 0; output = ""
    for m in regex.finditer(source_content):
        output += "".join([source_content[i:m.start()],
                           "<strong><span style='color:%s'>" % color[0:],
                           source_content[m.start():m.end()],
                           "</span></strong>"])

        i = m.end()
    outfile = open(filepath, 'w+')
    outfile.seek(0)
    outfile.write(output)
    print "\nProcess Completed!\n"
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()


raw_input()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows does acquire exclusive lock when opening a file, thus you can't open `infile` and `outfile` pointing at the same file.

Comment: Add the path to the filename when trying to open the file (and read krooliks comment too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because the python script doesn't have any knowledge about where the files are located that you want to open.

You have to provide the file path to open it as I have done below. I have simply concatenated the `source file path+'\\'+filename` and saved the result in a variable named as `filepath`. Now simply use this variable to open a file in `open()`.

```
import os
import sys

source = raw_input("Enter the source files path:")

listfiles = os.listdir(source)

for f in listfiles:
    filepath = source+'\\'+f # This is the file path
    infile = open(filepath, 'r')
```

Also there are couple of other problems with your code, if you want to open the file for both reading and writing then you have to use `r+` [mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). More over in case of Windows if you open a file using `r+` mode then you may have to use `file.seek()` before `file.write()` to avoid an other issue. You can read the reason for using the `file.seek()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11176772/2382792).

Comment: `os.path.join()` is better than hand munging file paths.

Comment: That does the same path join function. My problem is:

After highlighting the last instance of the search item, the script removes all the remaining contents after the last search instance in the output of each file.

Comment: @user3721167 You have modified your question to a different problem. You previous version of the question is already answered! This was your actual question:http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24200593/1 Please don't modify your question to represent a different problem. If you have a new problem then post a new question instead of editing the old question!

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what the error is:

```
No such file or directory: 'sample1.html'
```

Make sure the file exists. Or do a `try` statement to give it a default behavior.